# JAX-WS issue with custom exceptions after upgrading to java 7

Tags: exception, wsdl, jax-ws, java-7, jboss5.x

I had a `jaxws` web service written on `java 6` and deployed on `jboss 5.1`. After upgrading to `java7`, I have problems deploying it (see stacktrace below).
I googled this problem and it seems , that I need to use `@WebFault` annotation for my `custom Exception` and define `faultbean` for it. 
Problem is that due to some inner politics, I don't want my `wsdl` to change, but if i annotate exception class and create a faultbean for it, `WSDL` is changing.

Is there any other solution ?

this is the stacktrace :

```
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfsfile:/D:/projects/java-upgrade/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_5.1_Runtime_Server1382527942004/deploy/my-2.0.ear/my-2.0.jar/
       at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:177)
       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:362)
       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot build JAXB context
       at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.createJAXBContext(JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.java:984)
       at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSWebServiceMetaDataBuilder.buildWebServiceMetaData(JAXWSWebServiceMetaDataBuilder.java:154)
       at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSServerMetaDataBuilder.setupProviderOrWebService(JAXWSServerMetaDataBuilder.java:50)
       at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSMetaDataBuilderEJB3.buildMetaData(JAXWSMetaDataBuilderEJB3.java:76)
       at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.UnifiedMetaDataDeploymentAspect.start(UnifiedMetaDataDeploymentAspect.java:69)
       at org.jboss.wsf.framework.deployment.DeploymentAspectManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentAspectManagerImpl.java:129)
       at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.deployer.ArchiveDeployerHook.deploy(ArchiveDeployerHook.java:76)
       at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.deployer.AbstractWebServiceDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractWebServiceDeployer.java:60)
       at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.deployer.WebServiceDeployerEJB.internalDeploy(WebServiceDeployerEJB.java:113)
       at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
       ... 23 more
Caused by: org.jboss.ws.WSException: Failed to create JAXBContext
       at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.CustomizableJAXBContextFactory.createContext(CustomizableJAXBContextFactory.java:114)
       at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.createJAXBContext(JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.java:980)
       ... 33 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.
       this problem is related to the following location:
              at java.lang.StackTraceElement
              at public java.lang.StackTraceElement[] java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()
              at java.lang.Throwable
              at private java.lang.Throwable[] com.ws.jaxws.MyWsFaultBean.suppressed
              at com.ws.jaxws.MyWsFaultBean

       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102)
       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:448)
       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:297)
       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:139)
       at com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:105)
       at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.CustomizableJAXBContextFactory.createContext(CustomizableJAXBContextFactory.java:108)
       ... 34 more
```